# Why is AS telling me that `(ob instanceof Button)` is always `false`?

Tags: android-studio, instanceof

Why is AS telling me that `(ob instanceof Button)` is always `false`?

Also, it gives a "hint" to `'Cast to Button'`. If I take the hint, nothing changes.

```
  void setTextSizeForField(int textSize, Object ... obs){
    for(Object ob: obs)
           if (ob instanceof EditText) ((EditText) ob).setTextSize ( textSize );
      else if (ob instanceof TextView) ((TextView) ob).setTextSize ( textSize );
      else if (ob instanceof Button)   ((Button)   ob).setTextSize ( textSize/10 );
  }
```

The entire text of the message is:

```
Condition 'ob instanceof Button' is always 'false' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection analyzes method control and data flow to report possible conditions that are
 always true or false, expressions whose value is statically proven to be constant, and 
situations that can lead to nullability contract violations. 

Variables, method parameters and return values marked as @Nullable or @NotNull are 
treated as nullable (or not-null, respectively) and used during the analysis to check 
nullability contracts, e.g. report possible NullPointerException errors. 

More complex contracts can be defined using @Contract annotation, for example: 
@Contract("_, null -> null") — method returns null if its second argument is null

@Contract("_, null -> null; _, !null -> !null") — method returns null if
 its second argument is null and not-null otherwise

@Contract("true -> fail") — a typical assertFalse method which throws an
 exception if true is passed to it
The inspection can be configured to use custom @Nullable 

@NotNull annotations (by default the ones from annotations.jar will be used)
```

I'm not using annotations.

*** EDIT ***

If I swap the two `else if` statements, I get no warning and the code runs fine.

So I guess "never mind" could be in order, but what do you think AS was doing?

Comment: You people who vote down a question without comment should be barred from SO. HOW is it a bad question? I eagerly await your response.

Comment: OK. I get it. As it turns out it COULD be deemed a dumb question (except that there aren't any, I've often heard). Self-explanatory--as @Atreys kindly explained. I can't downvote myself (wouldn't if I could), but I get the point now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) shows that `Button` extends `TextView`, so that branch will never be taken.  If you invert your checks for `Button` and `TextView`, then different paths will be taken.

Comment: Ah. Thank you, @Atreys. I should have figured that out when I noticed swapping order changed outcome.